# Is it possible to change the font in Trello?

Tags: formatting, text-formatting

In Trello I'm noticing that a lowercase l (el) and an uppercase I (aye) look the same in a task.  I'm starting to use an open source font called `Source Sans Pro`.  I've tried changing it in my browser (`Firefox v16.0.1`) but it doesn't change the font in `Trello`.

Comment: This might be a browser-specific issue.  I'm still looking into it.  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Thanks for moving it for me.  Newbie mistake.

Found the answer!  Two parts, definitely browser-specific.
1) Change the font under Firefox Options -> Content -> Default font
2) Still had to state that pages should not be able to use their own font.  From #1, select Advanced and deselect "Allow pages to choose their own fonts".

Done!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33368/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-in-trello#comment25435_33368):

> Found the answer!
>
> 1. Change the font under Firefox Options -> Content -> Default font
> 2. Still had to state that pages should not be able to use their own font.  From #1, select Advanced and deselect "Allow pages to choose
>      their own fonts".
>
> Done!

Comment: hey @user26819 please register your account and login. Once done, you can post your comment as an answer and flag for removal of this, I'll be more than happy to do so.